# Cons (:) in CoffeeScript?

Tags: list, haskell, coffeescript

Haskell provides the `:` function to prepend an item to a list:

```
*Main> :t (:)
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

Example:

```
*Main> 1 : 2 : 3 : []
[1,2,3]
```

Does such a function/operator exist for CoffeeScript?

Comment: JavaScript has unshift, maybe CoffeeScript has too?

Comment: No but I have two suggestions (in addition to unshift) to achieve the same end: 1. chain calls to `.concat` like so `[2].concat([3]).concat([4]) => [2,3,4]` **or** if using in an enviroment that supports it you can inject something like the following raw JavaScript with backticks into your coffeescript (ES 6 only) `var list = [2,3,4]; var ints = [1, ...list];`. I don't think coffeescript's spread operator will work like this though.

Comment: if you just need a language that compiles to javascript and is quite lightweight there is always [purescript](http://www.purescript.org), which has [Lists](https://github.com/purescript/purescript-lists), note that other than haskell it has strict semantics

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, CoffeeScript does not implement Haskell-like lists.
The closest method/function is the [Array unshift method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unshift.asp)

However, the Haskell cons function creates a *new* list while preserving the original list, whereas `Array.unshift` modifies an existing array, so they really aren't the same
thing.

There are a number implementations of linked-lists in CoffeeScript, e.g.:

- [example 1](https://gist.github.com/aeharding/9846467)
- [example 2](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/blob/133fadd36ac36b3eaca44041502bcb88881b30aa/examples/computer_science/linked_list.coffee)

but I don't see anything natively supported by CoffeeScript.

Answer (score 1):

I'd second the native `unshift` method – although it will return the length of the resulting array, *not the array itself*, so you can't chain calls, like your example suggests.

As a fun alternative, [CoffeeScript's ranges feature allows splicing](http://coffeescript.org/#slices), which could be used to prepend a value to an existing array:

```
array = [ 1, 2, 3 ]

array[..0] = [ 4, array[0] ]

console.log array # [ 4, 1, 2, 3 ]
```

More precisely, it removes the first element of the array and adds the two elements on the right-hand side of the assignment (your desired prependand and the original 0-value).

We can even chain it, by wrapping it in parentheses and bringing in the array's referencing variable:

```
array = [ 1, 2, 3 ]

(( array[..0] = [ 4, array[0] ] ) and array).unshift(5)

console.log array # [ 5, 4, 1, 2, 3 ]
```